# C# - get values from Specflow feature file into NUnit (property) result file

Tags: c#, testing, automated-tests, nunit, specflow

we are using multiple different systems for our test (management). Now I want to transfer results of automated tests back into our test management tool. To do so, I need a test case ID of our test management tool to be carried from our automated test script to a point where I can easily handle it.

A part of our automated tests are C# NUnit tests. So, I started to use NUnit Properties to get the test case ID into NUnit result xml

```
[TestFixture, Property("TestCaseId", "ABC-12345")]
```

A second part of our tests are C# NUnit Specflow tests. Here I am struggling.
How do I get the test case ID from the Specflow feature file into the NUnit result XML file (best into the properties)?

Do you have some ideas for me?

Thanks
Nico

Comment: Does annotating the feature or scenarios with `@TestCaseId:ABC-12345` create the `[Property]` attribute above the test methods in the feature.cs file?

Comment: I used this way know. The property name is then Category and the value is TestCaseId:ABC-12345 but this is as well easy to identify.